# Neo4j Repository - Writing query with a dynamic where clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am relatively new to Neo4j, and have a doubt regarding writing of dynamic queries in Neo4j with spring.
From what I have read, the queries are annotated with @Query parameter in an interface that extends the GraphRepository class, and the dynamic parameters are supplied as argument.

But my requirement is such that I have to dynamically generate the number of where clauses.

```
For example,
@Query("match n where n.__type__='com.connectme.domain.Person' and n.age > {0} return n.id)
public List<Object> getPeopleWithAge(Integer age);//
```

My query can also change wherein age can also be less than some value, in which case, the query can become :

```
@Query("match n where n.__type__='com.connectme.domain.Person' and n.age > {0} and n.age <{1} return n.id)
public List<Object> getPeopleWithAge(Integer age1, Integer age2);//
```

In similar way, many clauses around the age parameter can lead to variation in where clauses.
How can i dynamically handle this as currently I am only aware of this annotated way of executing queries. 
Can I override and write my own custom queries ?

Comment: You can also use Neo4j-Template.query for custom queries or inherit from CypherDslRepository and use CypherDSL

Comment: Could you please elaborate more ? I am unfamiliar with what CypherDslREpository is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own custom query logic. First you create an extra interface containing the custom query method, so you get two repository interfaces

```
public interface YourRepository extends GraphRepository<SomeClass> implements YourRepositoryExtension{
    //inferred queries, annotated queries
}


public interface YourRepositoryExtension {
    EndResult<SomeClass> customQuery();
    Iterable<SomeClass> customTraversal();
}
```

Then you make an implementation:

```
@Repository
public class YourRepositoryImpl implements YourRepositoryExtension {

    @Autowired
    private YourRepository yourRepository;

    @Override
    public EndResult<SomeClass> customQuery(){
        //your query logic, using yourRepository to make cypher calls.
        return yourRepository.query("START n.. etc.. RETURN n", <optional params>);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<SomeClass> customTraversal(){
        SomeClass startNode = yourRepository.findOne(123);
        return yourRepository.findAllByTraversal(startNode, <some custom traversal>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but I dont fully understand this yet...How do i write the queries and would I have to implement GraphRepository in YourRepositoryImpl class ?

Comment: I've updated the example to be more elaborate. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. but thanks a lot for the explanation. Cleared an issue that was bugging me for quite some time.

Comment: @Wouter unfortunately this approach is no longer valid as GraphRepository does not contain query nor findAllByTraversal methods anymore. Do you happen to have a solution for this problem for spring-neo4j v. 5.1 ?